# my error : Class 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel' not found

Tags: laravel

[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bxDy.png)my composer.json:

```
...
  "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
...
```

I can run my project on localhost but when I upload on server I got this error message:

```
Class 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel' not found
```

my laravel version:

```
Laravel Framework 8.80.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure that you imported class in `config/app.php`
If not then please add below line in prividers array in `config/app.php` file.

`Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class`

then publish vendor by

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider" --tag=config
```

Then after

```
composer dump-autoload
```